# On Lebesgue integration

Tags: lebesgue-integral

How to prove that this function 
$$|\phi(x)|\left(2a+b(|u(x)|+|\phi(x)|)^{p-1}+b|u(x)|^{p-1}\right)$$
is in $L^{1}(\Omega)$, where  $u,\phi\in L^{p}(\Omega)$,$\Omega \subset \Bbb{R^{n}} $ be a bounded open set,  a,b are constants?

Comment: I've edited your question because using $\{,\}$ as delimiters tends to be confusing. Let me know if I've introduced an error. Something seems wrong here-should the second exponent also be outside some parentheses?

Comment: Yeah, this isn't true in current form: take $\Omega=[0,1],\phi=1,u=1/x,p=2,a=0,b=1$. $1+2/x$ is not in $L^1[0,1]$.

Comment: @kevin-carlson i cant able to understand is i did any mistake in my question

Comment: I do think there's a mistake in your question.

Comment: What is $\Omega$?

Comment: @davide-giraudo $\Omega \subset \Bbb{R^{n}}$ be a bounded open set

Answer (score 0):

I assume $p>1$. Since $(x+y)^p\leqslant 2^{p-1}(|x|^p+|y|^p)$ and $L^p(\Omega)\subset L^1(\Omega)$, we only have to prove that $|\phi|\cdot |u|^{p-1}$ is integrable. This is a consequence of Hölder's inequality.